# WPF mvvm switch view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism

I have a WPF application. I need to have two views : a "configuration" view, and a "main" view... I need to use Prism to apply the MVVM pattern.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751554/mvvm-wpf-change-smoothly-one-window-to-another). I tried to use this code :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:viewmodel1}" >
         <views:Usercontrol1/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:viewmodel2}" >
        <views:Usercontrol2/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding currentviewmodel}"/>
```

I created a Mainwindow and a UserControl and ViewModel for each view.

It says to create a command to modify the currentviewmodel... But how can I do it ? In my "configuration" view I have a "Save" button, and in the Save command I need to switch the view...

I also found [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views) but it's for mvvm light and I don't know how to modify "ViewModelBase" for Prism... and even if I could, this exemple have buttons in the MainWindow, but I need to switch the view from my "configuration" viewmodel...

Maybe there is a better way to do it...

Edit : still looking for a simple navigation example with mvvm and prism...

Comment: it seems to me your configuration VM should have a delegate `OnSaved()` which points to a method in the `Main` VM that simply switches the `currentviewmodel` property back. BTW, use correct casing for property names. it should be `CurrentViewModel`.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I want to do, but I'm a beginner... 1. How to point to a method in the Main VM ? 2. How to Switch the CurrentViewModel property ? What kind of property is it ?

Comment: I tried to add "public object CurrentViewModel { get; set; }" and "CurrentViewModel = _ConfigViewModel;" in the consctructor but i doesn't works..